# PHPBB 3.1.10 Dependency Injection of User Object only delivers Anonymous User in a live environment

Tags: ajax, symfony, dependency-injection, phpbb3, php-5.6

The goal is to get the login status of a User in **PHPBB 3.1.10** in an **Extension** Module using only **AJAX** calls.

I have succeded with this on XAMPP on my local machine. (meaning the problem described does not exist in that environment) I am now trying to roll that out to my online site by installing the extension on a live PHPBB Installation.

> The problem now is that as opposed to my local environment the @user
>   object delivered by the dependency injection mechanism is always
>   "Anonymous", no matter if I am logged in or not.

*"Anonymous" is the Username of a PHPBB User who is not logged in.*

- Both envrionments use PHPBB 3.1.10.
- The Folder Structure is deviates only in the name of the PHPBB3 Root Folder name.
- Both have functioning URL Rewrite now, after I had to manually set
  the Live Environments RewriteBase in .htaccess.
- Board Settings seem to be identical but for the domain.

As for PHP Server settings - I have no direct influence on PHP config on the live environmenht but for .htaccess and I have very little knowladge about what is possible in that regard.

Here is my Service Defintion, Routing Information and the Authorization class used to read the @user object.

> ext/foo/bar/services.yml

```
services:
    foo.bar.helper.auth:
        class: foo\bar\helper\Auth
        arguments:
            - '@user'
            - '%core.root_path%'
            - '%core.php_ext%'
```

> ext/foo/bar/config/routing.yml

```
foo_bar_getUserStatus:
    path: /getUserStatus
    defaults: { _controller: foo.bar.helper.Auth:getUserStatus }
```

> ext/foo/bar/helper/Auth.php

```
<?php

namespace foo\bar\helper;

class Auth{

    /* @var \phpbb\user */
    protected $user;

    /** @var string */
    protected $root_path;

    /** @var string */
    protected $php_ext;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param \phpbb\user  $user
     * @param string       $root_path
     * @param string       $php_ext php ext
     * @access public
     */
    public function __construct(
        \phpbb\user $user,
        $root_path, 
        $php_ext)
    {
        $this->user      = $user;
        $this->root_path = $root_path;
        $this->php_ext   = $php_ext;

        include_once($this->root_path 
        . 'includes/functions_user.' 
        . $this->php_ext);
    }

    // AUTHORIZATION
    public function __getUserStatus(){
        $userStatus = array( 'isLoggedIn' => false );

        if ($this->user->data['is_registered'] && ! $user->data['is_bot']){

            $userStatus['isLoggedIn'] = true;

            $ADMINS_GROUP_ID = '5';

            if(group_memberships($ADMINS_GROUP_ID, $this->user->data['user_id'], true)){
                $userStatus['isAdmin'] = true;
            }
        }
        return $userStatus;
    }

    public function getUserStatus(){
        return new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse(array(
            'success' => $this->__getUserStatus()
        ));
    }
}
```

> update 11.01.17

I have managed to get the extension to run properly on a fresh Installation of PHPBB 3.2 (which was released very recently) and PHP 7.0. (running in the same server environment as the live one)

I still have no idea yet why the user object was not set properly. 
Also I have not checked out yet if migrating data from PHPBB 3.1.10 to a fresh installation of PHPBB 3.2 is feasible for me.

*It will take some time for me to figure things out as I'm not working full time on it.*